# Integrate GeeTestTask(python3_anticaptcha) with selenium in python3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, captcha

I have a problem about python3_anticaptcha (api provided by anti-captcha.com), search on web, find support and try over a month but no luck.

API doc:
https://anticaptcha.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/API/pages/416972814/GeeTestTaskProxyless+-+captcha+from+geetest.com+without+proxy

I am doing a auto login on a website,   and copy the api on anti-captcha's doc:

```
def runGee(self, challenge):
    print("start gee")
    try:

        # Enter the key to the AntiCaptcha service from your account. Anticaptcha service key.
        ANTICAPTCHA_KEY = "mycode"
        # обязательные параметры
        websiteURL = "https:\/\/www.nike.com.hk"
        gt = "2328764cdf162e8e60cc0b04383fef81"
        print("sloving1")
        print("challenge:" ,challenge)
        # пример работы с GeeTestTask без прокси
        result = GeeTestTaskProxyless.GeeTestTaskProxyless(anticaptcha_key=ANTICAPTCHA_KEY,
                                                           websiteURL=websiteURL,
                                                           gt=gt).captcha_handler(challenge=challenge)
        print("sloving2")
        print(result)
        print("--end gee--")
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        print("--end with error--")
```

However, the geetask start over 3 minute(or more), and got error everytime. usually error code like:

```
{'errorId': 34, 'errorCode': 'ERROR_TOKEN_EXPIRED', 'errorDescription': 'Captcha provider 
reported that additional variable token has expired.', 'taskId': 1204556667}
```

or

```
{'errorId': 12, 'errorCode': 'ERROR_CAPTCHA_UNSOLVABLE', 'errorDescription': '  Captcha 
could not be solved by 5 different workers.', 'taskId': 1204060350}
```

..etc

depends on what parameter i passed.

May i know am i passing the right value to geetask? or some wrong on the code?
Moreover, if geetest return the correct value, i need to do any else to pass capcha(or pass code to geetest server) or GeeTestTaskProxyless already done(not to do anything)?

it is extremely hard to me, does anyone had used this api successfully? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems for me that those errors are because of proxy (if you use any) or just bad IP.
Personally, I use another captcha service and I didn't have such problems with it.
I advice you to try it, it's actually much easier: https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#solving_geetest

You should send a request like this one:

> https://2captcha.com/in.php?key=1abc234de56fab7c89012d34e56fa7b8&method=geetest&gt=f1ab2cdefa3456789012345b6c78d90e&challenge=12345678abc90123d45678ef90123a456b&api_server=api-na.geetest.com&pageurl=https://www.example.com/page/

What you need to archieve is to get correct answer from it, like this one:

> {
>         "challenge":"1a2b3456cd67890e12345fab678901c2de",
>         "validate":"09fe8d7c6ba54f32e1dcb0a9fedc8765",
>         "seccode":"12fe3d4c56789ba01f2e345d6789c012|jordan" }

Then you just need to implement that answer on a site. Just read the first link I gave you.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, i may decide to change my provider. But i am not very understand "5. Use the values received from our API to submit your request to the target website placing the values into corresponding request fields:" How can i do that?

Comment: Well, as far as I get it (I work with another captcha types, like graphic captcha and ReCaptcha mostly), to submit the answer you nned to send a POST request to the site you work at. First you should open Network Monitor in your browser and then solve the captcha manually. You'll see the request that goes to the server and it must contain those 3 parameters: geetest_challenge, geetest_validate, geetest_seccode
Then, when next time you solve captcha via 2captcha, you just send the same request to the site, but you put in it those parameters from 2captcha's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the anticaptcha but in the geetest provider.
The token challenger can only be used once, when your browser loads the geetest captcha it expires the token.
To fix this problem, you only need to block the request that consumes the token in your browser.
go to devtools and add the block for the geestest captcha API in the browser, like this:

[image]

You can automatically integrate this into the selenium with the following command:

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setBlockedURLs', {"urls": ["api.geetest.com/get.php"]})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.enable', {})
```